# Embolden upper part of curve

Tags: r

How do I embolden only a certain part of a curve? In this case the efficient frontier, which is the top half.

The following is my code

```
#portfolio contains my data
portfolio<-read.table(........)

#this plots a scatter plot, however type="n" so nothing shows up
plot(portfolio$PortfolioRisk,portfolio$PortfolioReturn, xlab = "Risk", ylab 
= "Return", type = "n")


curv <- loess(portfolio$PortfolioReturn~portfolio$PortfolioRisk)

lines(curv)

points(0.15,0.20, pch = 21, bg = 1)
points(0.20,0.25, pch = 21, bg = 1)
text(c(0.15,0.20), c(0.20,0.25), labels=c("B", "E"), cex=0.8, pos =1)
```

My graph:

[image]

One solution I though of is halving my data into lower and upper halves and plotting the lines separately with different lwd="", however I don't think that will work because the data is not continuous

EDIT: Here is the data

```
     PortfolioReturn PortfolioRisk
1            0.275        0.4355
2            0.270        0.3772
3            0.265        0.3245
4            0.260        0.2774
5            0.255        0.2359
6            0.250        0.2000
7            0.245        0.1697
8            0.240        0.1451
9            0.235        0.1260
10           0.230        0.1126
11           0.225        0.1048
12           0.220        0.1026
13           0.215        0.1060
14           0.210        0.1151
15           0.205        0.1297
16           0.200        0.1500
17           0.195        0.1759
18           0.190        0.2074
19           0.185        0.2445
20           0.180        0.2872
21           0.175        0.3355
```

Comment: Could you provide data and code to reproduce this?

Comment: Overplot the part you want to emphasize

Comment: @jay.sf Edited, with data.

Comment: @OvermanZarathustra Works similar as code given in my answer, use `lines` and `loess` but do it separately for upper and lower part and specify line width `lwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot both parts separately. Here an example since you didn't provide data.

```
curve(sqrt(x), xlim=c(0, 4), ylim=c(-4, 4), lwd=4)
curve(-sqrt(x), add=TRUE)
points(1, sqrt(1), pch=21, bg=1)
points(.5, -sqrt(.5), pch=21, bg=1)
text(c(1,.5), c(sqrt(1),-sqrt(1)), labels=c("B", "E"), cex=0.8, pos =1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, more or less automatic to do what the question asks for. Note that it subsets the vectors with indices `1:m`. My first attempt was `m:curv$n` and got the *lower* part of the curve. Adapt this solution on a case by case basis.

The first instructions are nearly equal to the code posted in the question. The difference is in the call to `loess`, that uses argument `data`.

```
plot(portfolio$PortfolioRisk,
     portfolio$PortfolioReturn, 
     xlab = "Risk", ylab = "Return", type = "n")


curv <- loess(PortfolioReturn ~ PortfolioRisk, data = portfolio)
```

Now the new part.

```
m <- which.min(curv$x)
lines(curv)
lines(curv$x[1:m], curv$y[1:m], lwd = 2)
```

And finally the instructions to make it pretty.

```
points(0.15,0.20, pch = 21, bg = 1)
points(0.20,0.25, pch = 21, bg = 1)
text(c(0.15,0.20), c(0.20,0.25), labels=c("B", "E"), cex=0.8, pos =1)
```

[image]